# concatenate 2d list with list comprehension instead of a for loop

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Hi I have a 2d list that has 3 elements
I have concatenated some of the elements using the following code

```
    list1 = [(1,"hello",3),(1,"excelent",4),(2,"marvelous",3)]
    length = len(list1)
    text = ''
    for irow in range(length):
            number      = list1[irow][0]
            listText    = list1[irow][1]
            ids         = list1[irow][2]
            text += "<tag id = "+ str(ids)+">"+str(listText)+"<\\tag>\r\n"
    
    print(text)
```

and this produces the following output

```
<tag id = 3>hello<\tag> 
<tag id = 4>excelent<\tag> 
<tag id =3>marvelous<\tag>
```

and this is correct, my question is there a way to do this using list comprehension, or is there a more pythonic way of achieving this same outcome.

Comment: Where is `length` defined?

Comment: See [`jinja templates`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/) if you need more complex rendering..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reduce the whole thing to a one-liner, but I suggest that a reasonable compromise is probably still to use a `for` loop over your list, but in the `for` loop target you can unpack the sublists directly into the relevant variables.  In any case there is no need for looping over index rather than the actual contents of `list1`.  Using an f-string (in recent Python versions) will also help tidy things up.

```
list1 = [(1,"hello",3),(1,"excelent",4),(2,"marvelous",3)]

text = ''
for number, listText, ids in list1:
    text += f'<tag id = {ids}>{listText}<\\tag>\r\n'

print(text)
```

You could also consider using the conventional dummy variable `_` in place of `number` here, because you are not actually using the value:

```
for _, listText, ids in list1:
```

Answer (score 1):

Using list-comprehension:

```
ee = [(1,"hello",3),(1,"excelent",4),(2,"marvelous",3)]
  
print(["<tag id = "+ str(x[2])+">"+str(x[1])+"<\tag>" for x in ee])
```

OUTPUT:

```
['<tag id = 3>hello<\tag>', '<tag id = 4>excelent<\tag>', '<tag id = 3>marvelous<\tag>']
```

Edit:

If you want to have the double quotes in the tags text:

```
print(["<tag id = " + str(x[2])+" >" + str('"' + x[1] + '"') + "<\tag>" for x in ee])
```

OUTPUT:

```
['<tag id = 3 >"hello"<\tag>', '<tag id = 4 >"excelent"<\tag>', '<tag id = 3 >"marvelous"<\tag>']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using f-strings and unpacking the tuple elements in the list comprehension makes this neatly readable:

```
list1 = [
    (1, "hello", 3),
    (1, "excelent", 4),
    (2, "marvelous", 3),
]
texts = [
    f'<tag id="{ids}">{text}<\\tag>'  # TODO: handle HTML quoting?
    for (number, text, ids) in list1
]
text = "\r\n".join(texts)
```

Answer (score 0):

iterate lambda function and use `map()`

```
list1 = [(1, "hello", 3), (1, "excelent", 4), (2, "marvelous", 3)]
text = map(lambda x: f'<tag id = {x[2]}>{x[1]}<\\tag>', list1)
print('\r\n'.join(list(text)))
```

Comment: There are many ways you can solve this problem but using map function will make your code clean and readable.